# Why wouldn't we use INNER JOIN on a Table Valued Function?

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions

After searching online I have not been able to find anything that suggests you can or should use INNER JOIN with a table valued function and I'm curious, why? For example, there is a very common TVF that SSRS report developers use for multi-valued parameters in reports, so they can parse the results as a table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ParmSplit] (
    @List nvarchar(MAX),
    @SplitOn nchar(1) )

RETURNS @RtnValue TABLE (
    SplitValue nvarchar(250) )
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE (CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@List) > 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @RtnValue (SplitValue)
        SELECT SplitValue = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List,1,CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@List) - 1)))
        SET @List = SUBSTRING(@List,CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@List) + LEN(@SplitOn), LEN(@List))
    END

    INSERT INTO @RtnValue (SplitValue)
    SELECT SplitValue = LTRIM(RTRIM(@List))
    RETURN
END
```

Ok so lets imagine we have a states table, and in our report we have a states multi-valued parameter. We want to match the states passed in the parameter to states in a table. Here is the states table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE #StateTable (
    StatID int IDENTITY (1,1)
    ,StateCode char(2) );
```

Insert some records:

```
INSERT INTO #StateTable 
SELECT 'AL';        
INSERT INTO #StateTable 
SELECT 'AK';        
INSERT INTO #StateTable 
SELECT 'AZ';        
INSERT INTO #StateTable 
SELECT 'AR';        
INSERT INTO #StateTable 
SELECT 'CA';        
INSERT INTO #StateTable 
SELECT 'CO';        
INSERT INTO #StateTable 
SELECT 'CT';        
INSERT INTO #StateTable 
SELECT 'DE';        
INSERT INTO #StateTable 
SELECT 'DC';        
INSERT INTO #StateTable 
SELECT 'FL';        
INSERT INTO #StateTable 
SELECT 'GA';        
INSERT INTO #StateTable 
SELECT 'GU';        
INSERT INTO #StateTable 
SELECT 'HI';        
INSERT INTO #StateTable 
SELECT 'ID';        
INSERT INTO #StateTable 
SELECT 'IL';        
INSERT INTO #StateTable 
SELECT 'IN';        
INSERT INTO #StateTable 
SELECT 'IA';        
INSERT INTO #StateTable 
SELECT 'KS';        
INSERT INTO #StateTable 
SELECT 'KY';        
INSERT INTO #StateTable 
SELECT 'LA';        
INSERT INTO #StateTable 
SELECT 'ME';        
INSERT INTO #StateTable 
SELECT 'MD';
```

Now query using the TVF and an INNER JOIN

```
DECLARE @MultiValuedParameter varchar(500) = 'IA, KS, KY, LA, ME, MD, IN, IL'

SELECT
    StateCode
FROM #StateTable s
INNER JOIN dbo.ParmSplit(@MultiValuedParameter, ',')  p ON s.StateCode = p.SplitValue​
```

The same query using CROSS APPLY.

```
DECLARE @MultiValuedParameter varchar(500) = 'IA, KS, KY, LA, ME, MD, IN, IL'

SELECT
    StateCode
FROM #StateTable
CROSS APPLY dbo.ParmSplit(@MultiValuedParameter, ',')
WHERE SplitValue = StateCode
```

The CROSS APPLY requires a WHERE clause which effectively creates an INNER JOIN.

I was always curious about this. Even though this example only returns a single column, you could still apply this to a multi-column table result. Why when we talk about TVF are we only supposed to use CROSS APPLY?

Comment: I have used TVF with left and inner joins with no issues.

Comment: I would also toss that splitter function you have in the trash. It is a multi-statement table valued function that has loops inside. It is a performance timebomb. You need to replace that splitter with a set based splitter instead. Here are several better options. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: @SeanLange This isn't very different from the recursive CTE in your link, which performs quite well with smaller strings (our use-case).

Comment: Except that your code is using a loop which is horribly inefficient. And I wouldn't use that cte version anyway as it is not very fast either. I would use CLR or the XML version posted on Aaron's blog. Look at the performance results of his testing. Feel free to continue using your loop version but at some point it is going to blow up a query and you will drive yourself crazy trying to figure out why.

Comment: + 1000 on everything Sean said... Here's a link to Jeff Moden's DelimitedSplit8K splitter function http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Comment: I looked at the tally table function that Jason linked. When used with APPLY or INNER JOIN, I only get the first delimited result from the string. I just replaced the function in my original post with this one for testing, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In reality, you wouldn't/shouldn't do this. You are applying a TVF with a static value. APPLY (CROSS or OUTER) should be used when the parameter will be dynamic from your dataset.

Any who says you need/should to use APPLY with a TVF? You showed it using a JOIN and I can also see the value is using it as a sub-query.

Comment: If you google table valued function and inner join, every result instructs you to use CROSS APPLY. That's why I posted this. I couldn't find one result that included INNER JOIN in it's solution.